# rake test:units aborted but why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently going through Agile Development With Rails 4th edition (Rails 3.2+). I am trying to preform a unit test the for the "Product" model:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   test "product attributes must not be empty" do
    product = Product.new
    assert product.invalid?
    assert product.errors[:title].any?
    assert product.errors[:description].any?
    assert product.errors[:price].any?
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
  end
end
```

This is word for word what the book has, and there is no errata that says otherwise. When I run:

```
rake test:units
```

I get back the following:

```
Run options: 

# Running tests:

F

Finished tests in 0.079901s, 12.5155 tests/s, 25.0310 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test_product_attributes_must_not_be_empty(ProductTest) [/Users/robertquinn/rails_work/depot/test/unit/product_test.rb:7]:
Failed assertion, no message given.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/robertquinn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-...]

Tasks: TOP => test:units
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Robert-Quinns-MacBook-Pro:depot robertquinn$
```

Here are my Product model validations:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image_url, :price, :title

  validates :description, :image_url, :price, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
    }
end
```

I cannot figure out why this rake is being aborted. The test created an empty "Product" object which is thus invalid, and should have errors for every attribute. However, it appears the rake aborts upon hitting the first assertion against the ":title" attribute. I am absolutely clueless here. Any and all input would be appreciated.

Comment: It's aborting because your tests failed. Uncomment each assertion to figure out which one is failing and go from there.

Comment: What validations do you have on the Product model, then?

Comment: After individually commenting out each assertion, the one causing the issue is "assert product.errors[:title].any?" In response, I removed the validation on :title "validates :title, uniqueness: true" to see if that would fix it, but still no luck.

Comment: you need to add `presence: true` to your `:title` validations

Comment: AWESOME! That fixed it. Since there is not an answer for this question, if you post that in the answer section I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

By only validating the uniqueness of the title you still allow for titles that are nil, which makes your test fail. You need to change your validation to

```
validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

I also suggest you add messages to your assertions. This makes it much easier to see which assertion is failing:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   test "product attributes must not be empty" do
    product = Product.new
    assert product.invalid?, "Empty product passed validation"
    assert product.errors[:title].any?, "Missing title passed validation"
    assert product.errors[:description].any?, "Missing description passed validation"
    assert product.errors[:price].any?, "Missing price passed validation"
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?, "Missing image URL passed validation"
  end
end
```